# Вывести разницу между максимальной и минимальной ценой в отдельный столбец SQL

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Как вывести разницу между макс/мин ценой в отдельный столбец?

Таблица:

[image: Текст]

Answer (score 0):

Это решается элементерным запросом:

```
select  max(`Цена`) - min(`Цена`) as `Разница цен` from `внешний аккумулятор`;
```